# De/Encode all items in list with Python

Tags: python, list, encoding

How can I decode or encode all items in a list?

My idea is simple:

```
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    list1[i]=list1[i].decode('utf-8')
```

But I'm curious if isn't there some built-in function to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list1[:] = [x.decode('utf-8') for x in list1]
```

Using `list1[:] = [...]` will alter the list object that that list1 is bound to, which means any other objects referencing that list will also be modified - eg: it's an "in-place".

Using list1 = [...] will create a new list object and re-bind it to the name list1, which means any other objects referencing the same list will not reflect any changes.

```
list1 = [x.decode('utf-8') for x in list1]
```

Comment: Might be handy explaining the `[:]` - that's often a source of confusion :)

Comment: @JonClements, Thank you for comment. I updated the explanation. But I am not sure if it is clear.

Comment: Maybe something like: "Using `list1[:] = [...]` will alter the `list` object that that `list1` is bound to, which means any other objects referencing that list will see the changes - eg: it's an "in-place" operation. Using `list1 = [...]` will create a new `list` object and re-bind it to the name `list1`, which means any other objects referencing the same list will not reflect any changes"... But yeah... agreed, it's a tricky one to explain nicely :)

Comment: @JonClements, I used your comment. At least, yous is more clear than mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lambda` statement combined with the built-in function `map` :

```
list1 = map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'), list1)
```

Note that it will copy the base list : you don't need to use `[:]`